# New to Java: How do I utilize a return type in an if else statement?

Tags: java

So I have a method called `"canMove()"` with a boolean return type. How would I go about utilizing a return type like that in an `if else` statement in another method?

For example:

```
if (canMove() return true) {

}
```

Comment: what do you want to do if `false` ?

Comment: I'm not worried about the else portion right now, just the syntax of using something like this in an if else.

Comment: Your are not worried but I am.  The question can not be answered without this knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
if(canMove()){
//enter code here
}
else{
//enter code here
}
```

Because since canMove() returns either True or False, it can be interpreted as if(true) when canMove() returns true.

Answer (score 0):

For booleans, it is simple:

```
if (canMove()) { // function returns true
 // ...
}
else { // function returns false
 // ...
}
```

Comment: That is calling the method twice if it fails

Answer (score 0):

You can store the return value of `canMove` in a variable

e.g.

```
boolean rv = canMove();
if (rv) 
   return rv;

// do other processing?
```

If there is no other processing than you could just return the result without needing to store it in another variable

```
return canMove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is wrong

```
if (canMove() return true) {

}
```

you can not return result within the condition if else work like below

```
if(condition){
//your logic 
   return true
} else{
//your logic

  return false
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet. So I will write some comment here. 
I don't know exactly what you want. But I have suggessted for you.

First case: You use method canMove() in other class -> let use method

```
public static boolean canMove() { 
         if (right) {   
           return true;
         } 
         return false
}
```

Second case: In the same class -> you just call method `canMove()` and do need nothing.

```
if (canMove()) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to return **true** if the method **canMove()** returns true, and return **false** if the method **canMove()** returns false, you can simply write:

```
return canMove();
```

NEVER EVER write this:

```
if (canMove()) {
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

However, if you want to do some processing before returning from the other function, there are several ways to do do it.

Novice people usually write this way:

```
if (canMove()) {
  do something here;
  return true;
}
else {
  do something else here;
  return false;
}
```

But writing like this will be cleaner:

```
if (canMove()) {
  do something here;
  return true;
}

do something else here;
return false;
```

You don't need "**else**", because when the evaluation of the "**if**" is true, it already returns out of the function anyway. It is called Early Return Principle. Leveraging this principle allows you to write less **if-else**, and can avoid nested **if-else** in many cases.

Naive people will argue about multiple points of exit/return in one function, but it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below: 
as canMove() returns boolean it will return either true or false so you can use like below

```
if (canMove()) { 

 //canMove() is true... do something

}
else { 

 //canMove() is false... do something else

}
```